# onChange is not fired when TextField becomes empty

Tags: swift, swiftui

Typing on the keyboard fires `.onChange` as expected so "changed" is printed to the console correctly, except when the user deletes all characters from the `TextField`.

```swift
struct CurrencyInput: View {
    @State var value: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Amount", value: $value, format: .number)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .onChange(of: value) {
                print("changed")
                print(value)
            }
    }
}
```

Starting with the empty `TextField` and then typing the digit 2 followed by a backspace I would expect this

### Expected console log

```
changed
2
changed
0
```

However, I only get this

### Actual console log

```
changed
2
```

Changing the `TextField` binding to a `String` seems to solve the issue, but then I cannot use the formatter.

```swift
struct CurrencyInput: View {
    @State var value: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Amount", text: $value)
            .onChange(of: value) {
                print("changed")
                print(value)
            }
    }
}
```

The above code correctly console logs this:

```
changed
2
changed
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that an empty `TextField` is treated as `0` if the binding variable is a `Double`. But I still believe that `.onChange` should be called. Any ideas on how I can be notified when the user deletes all characters?

Comment: Your example cannot be correct how can `print(value)` output an A when `value` is a Double?

Comment: Yeah sorry old code, the letter A should be the digit 2. Updated it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot detect this using `onChange`, because `value` does not *change*. When the textfield becomes empty, the parsing fails so `value` does not change.

You can use an optional `Double`, i.e. `Double?` to detect when the text changes from parseable to unparseable, and vice versa:

```
@State var value: Double?

var body: some View {
    TextField("Amount", value: $value, format: .number)
        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        .onChange(of: value) {
            print("changed")
            if let value {
                print(value)
            }
        }
}
```

For example, the text field is initially empty, and you type in "1", `onChange` will get called (`value` changes from nil to 1). Deleting the "1" will also cause `onChange` to get called (`value` changes from 1 to nil).

However, this cannot detect every text change. For example, when the text changes from `A` to `B`, `onChange` does not get called, because both texts are unparseable, and `value` stays the same (nil).

If you want to detect *every* text change, you *need* to use a `String`. It is still possible to have a `Double` property. You can write it as a computed property that parses the `String` state.

```
var value: Double? {
    try? FloatingPointFormatStyle.number.parseStrategy.parse(text)
}

@State var text: String = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("Amount", text: $text)
        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        .onChange(of: text) {
            print("changed")
            if let value {
                print(value)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Using `Double?` solved the issue! Thanks!